# How do I sort to this code with Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have list which is about student and his/her grade. I want to two things. One of them is first choice; add a student and his/her grade. Second of them is second choice; quit and sorting all students with alphabetic order.

True algorithm in the answer.

Comment: It should be obvious that you need a call to `sort` or `sorted` in there somewhere. I'm not inclined to do your homework for you though.

Comment: So what is your problem? What are you stuck on? Judging from some answers, it's not very clear what you are asking for.

Comment: It was very clear, and I have an answer from @Skyler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `grades[student] = hishergrade`. You didn't define the variables `student` and `hishergrade`, instead you use `name` and `phone` for that.
2. You didn't sort before print them at all.

So your code should be modifed as:

```
def print_menu():
    print('1. Add a student and his/her grade')
    print('2. Quit and Sort')


grades = {}
menu_choice = 0
print_menu()
while menu_choice != 2:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-2): "))
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print("Add Student and His/Her Grade")
        name = input("Student: ")
        phone = input("Grade: ")
        grades[name] = phone #Use the right variables
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        print("Grades:")
        for x in sorted(grades.keys()):  #Sort
            print("Student: ", x, "\tGrade:", grades[x])
            print()
        print_menu()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure about what you're asking, but maybe this is what you need?

```
print("Grades:")
keys = list(grades.keys())
keys.sort()
for x in keys:
    print("Student: ", x, "\tGrade:", grades[x])
    print()
    print_menu()
```